# Unable to run jar executable in path on linux

Tags: java, linux, jar, archlinux

I installed the clojure-lsp according to the instructions on the [repository](https://github.com/snoe/clojure-lsp), and put the jar in `/usr/bin`.

My problem is that I get the error `Error: Unable to access jarfile clojure-lsp` when I run `clojure-lsp`, but it seems to works when I run it with sudo.

this is the permissions I have on the executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 20822380 Oct 15 11:05 /usr/bin/clojure-lsp
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the clojure-lsp jar 10 Minutes ago on my arch linux box. Is installed it as root `sudo -s` and forgot to exit from root environment before I had run it the first time. It worked! After that I recognized my failure and exit from root. Then I ran it  again and it failed with "can not access /tmp/lsp.out permission denied". The obvious solution was that the executable had created a file in /tmp with root permissions. I removed this file and restarted and all went well.

It is not the same observation like yours, but perhaps it gives you a clue. I dont't know the conditions you started your installation the first time and, I don't know  your OS setup, so it's really hard to help.

Perhaps you've switched on kernel security (like apparmor,...). ??

clojure-lsp is both, a script and a jar file. Internally it starts java. This java opens a jar file at the path $0/closure-lsp (/usr/bin/closure-lsp in you special case). I would interpret the reported error the way, that Java has no access to that file. Perhaps java has no access to /usr/bin. But that would be very strange.

Do you run closure-lsp from a bash / other shell. Do you have java installed and in your PATH? (`java -version` should work)

Comment: I stumbled on the same problem as you and I fixed it the same way. I am using fish and your answer gave me th eidea to try it in another more standard shell. This solved this problem. But now i get a NullPointerException from the lsp when launching my editor... Thanks anyways!